# in place editing using awk

Tags: linux, awk

I want to add a line at top of file say `f1` using awk.
Is there a better way than the following?

```
awk 'BEGIN{print "word"};{print $0}' f1 > aux;cp aux f1;\rm aux<br/>
```

Does awk has something like `-i` option in sed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use sed - it would make the solution more straightforward

```
$sed -i.bak '1i\
word
' <filename>
```

Comment: How can I echo newlines using the above script

Answer (score 1):

An alternate way to do this is:

```
sed -i '1s:^: Word1\nWord2 :' file
```