# Don't treat variable content as special characters in sed

Tags: bash, sed

I have the following `sed` command:

```
sed -i "4i\ $CHANGES" ./CHANGELOG.rst
```

However, my `$CHANGES` variable looks something like this:

```
title
-----

* list
  * elem
  * elem
```

Hence, the above command fails with the following error: `sed: -e expression #1, char 149: unknown command: '*'`. I understand that this happens because the contents of the `$CHANGES` variable are somewhat interpreted, but how do I specify to only use the string in the variable as a raw string, without interpreting its contents?

Comment: Where is the content of `$CHANGES` coming from? If it is a file, we can work from that with `sed ... r`.

Comment: No, it's a variable built in the same script, before I need to add its contents to the specified file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
sed -i "4 i\
${CHANGES//$'\n'/\\$'\n'}" ./CHANGELOG.rst
```

As @NeronLeVelu notes,

- you need a newline after `i\`
- newlines in text passed to `sed`'s `i` function must be `\`-escaped - this is what the bash parameter (variable) substitution above does.

Comment: @AndreiHorak My pleasure; glad to hear it.

Answer (score 2):

Another good old "use AWK instead" style answer...

If you just want to insert that string on line 4, you could do so in AWK like this:

```
awk -v var="$CHANGES" 'NR == 4 { print var } { print }' ./CHANGELOG.rst > tmp && mv tmp ./CHANGELOG.rst
```

This would insert the contents of your variable `$CHANGES` before line 4 in your file.

As mentioned in the comments and [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16529730/2088135), newer versions of `gawk` (>= 4.1.0) can do in-place editing:

```
gawk -i inplace -v var="$CHANGES" 'NR == 4 { print var } { print }' ./CHANGELOG.rst
```

Saving you a few characters.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, AWK doesn't support in-place editing. Funny you should mention it though, the typical answer to that question would be "use sed instead"! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/910121/in-place-editing-using-awk

Comment: It does... but just in new versions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16529716/awk-save-modifications-inplace

Comment: Even `sed -i` just hides the details of a temporary file; it still writes to one and renames it to the original behind the scenes.

Answer (score 2):

```
sed "4 i\
$CHANGES" ./CHANGELOG.rst
```

- Need a new line after the `i\`
- On some sed a space before the `i`
- $Changes must have all new line escaped with `\`

so awk is better in this case. Another way is to use sed with a temporary file (`i` insert before and `r`append file so 1 line before)

```
echo "${CHANGES}" > TempoFile
sed "3 r TempoFile" YourFile
rm TempoFile
```

Answer (score 1):

Good old ed:

```
$ CHANGES="title
-----

* list
  * elem
  * elem"

$ seq 10 > file

$ ed file <<END
4i
$CHANGES
.
w
q
END
21
59

$ cat file
1
2
3
title
-----

* list
  * elem
  * elem
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```